# A finite group with the property that all of its proper subgroups are abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with the property that all of its proper subgroups are abelian. Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Prove that either $N$ is contained in the center of $G$ or else $G$ has a normal abelian subgroup of prime index.

I think $G$ is solvable. *http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/every-finite-group-whose-every-proper-subgroup-is-abelian-is-solvable/*. I hope that idea maybe usefull.

Help me some hints.

Thanks a lot.

P/s: This is a question comes from a qualifying exam in Algebra ( Wisconsin August $1979$ )

Comment: There is a paper on this subject which describes completely these groups. You can see "http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1903-004-04/S0002-9947-1903-1500650-9/S0002-9947-1903-1500650-9.pdf"

Comment: I can't see this problem in that paper. Can you notice me @Babgen ?

Comment: No, I didn't say that your problem is there. For more detail about these groups you can see this paper.

Comment: Ehm ... of course :)

Comment: How can I download qualifying exam in Algebra from Wisconsin?

Comment: You can follow the link http://math.library.wisc.edu/reserve/qualifying-exams.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Or you could argue as follows. Suppose that $N \not \subseteq Z(G)$. Let $M$ be a maximal normal subgroup of $G$ containing $N.$ Then $M = C_{G}(N)$ as $M$ is Abelian and $M$ is proper, but $N \not \subseteq Z(G).$ Then certainly $M = C_{G}(M).$ Hence $M$ is in fact a maximal subgroup of $G,$ for if $M$ is contained in another proper subgroup $H$ of $G$
normal or not) then $H$ s Abelian, so $H \subseteq C_{G}(M) = M$ and $H = M.$ Hence $G/M$ is a simple group (as $M$ is maximal normal) with no proper non-identity subgroup
(as $M$ is not contained in any proper subgroup of $G$). But $G/M$ contains a cyclic subgroup of prime order (you don't even need Cauchy's theorem to see this), so $G/M$ is in fact cyclic of prime order.

Comment: Can you explain why $G/M$ contains a cyclic subgroup of prime order?

Comment: Well, let $X$ be any finite group with more that one element. Choose $x$ to be any non-identity element of $X.$ Then $\langle x \rangle$ is cyclic of order $n >1.$ Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $n.$ Then $x^{\frac{n}{p}}$ has prime order $p.$

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: Finally, can you explain why $G/M$ is cyclic?

Comment: Use the isomorphism theorems. $M$ is not contained in any proper subgroup of $G.$ But $G/M$ has a subgroup of order $p.$ This means that $G$ has a subgroup $X$ which contains $M$ and has order $p|M|.$ But then $X$ must be all of $G$ and $G/M$ is cyclic of order $p.$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson, can you elaborate on this problem? I'm struggling still to understand the problem, my understanding is new but if you could add some details or commentary between steps, that would really help

Comment: @cele : You need to be more specific about where you have problems. The argument is already broken into quite small steps.

Comment: How do we know that $N \neq G$?

Comment: @user515430 : You have a point. I was thinking that the question intended N to be proper. You need a bit more argument if that is not the intention. I deal with the case that G has a proper normal non central subgroup. Except for that case, G/Z(G) is simple. If Z(G) is non-trivial , then it's easy to finish be induction. If G is simple, then I think you might need to use Burnside's transfer theorem. If P is a non-trivial Sylow subgroup of G, then P is Abelian and not normal, so N_G(P) is Abelian, and G has a normal p- complement, contrary to simplicity.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finite_non-abelian_and_every_proper_subgroup_is_abelian_implies_not_simple gives a counting argument to prove that $G$ cannot be simple.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I would argue:

- Show that the centralizer of $N$ in $G$ is also normal and contains $N$. So either $N$ is contained in the center, or we replace it with its centralizer, which is also a proper normal abelian subgroup of $G$.
- Repeating the previous step as many times as needed ends with either the conclusion that $N$ is in the center or that $N$ is its own centralizer, and also a proper normal abelian subgroup of $G$.
- In the latter case consider the homomorphism $f:G/N\to Aut(N)$ gotten by conjugation action. Show that it has to be injective.
- If $G/N$ has a proper cyclic subgroup $K/N$ show that $K/N\le \ker f$.
- Conclude that $G/N$ must be cyclic of prime order.

Comment: Yeah: As Geoff's answer explains, we don't need to do many iterations in step one. As $N$ grows, its centralizer can only shrink, so one round will do.